# Ruby on Rails Tutorial - test, reset password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with understanding one code in Michael Hartl's tutorial.

In `PasswordResetsTest` class, in test `password resets` we took our user from fixtures, we posted to `password_resets_path` with right mail and we asserted that `@user.reset_digest` doesn't equal `@user.reload.reset_digest`.
Later, Michael said we need to use assigns method to be able to patch to `password_reset_path`. He said it's because our user from fixtures doesn't have `reset_token`, because it is created only in create_reset_digest method.
I understand it, but I don't get one thing - why `assert_not_equal` with pre- and post- reload user's `reset_digest` passes?
I thought it goes like this: `reset_digest` is `nil` at first, we post to `password_resets_path`, which is create action of `PasswordResetsController`; in this action we have `create_reset_digest` method. `reset_digest` isn't nil anymore, we reload it and our assert_not_equal passes.

But if so, `@user` from fixtures should also have `reset_token` now (if its `reset_digest` was influenced by create action (specifically `create_reset_digest` method).

Can someone please take a look? :)

```rb
require 'test_helper'

class PasswordResetsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    def setup
        ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
        @user = users(:michael)
        end

        test "password resets" do
            get new_password_reset_path
            assert_template 'password_resets/new'
            # Invalid email
            post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: "" }
            assert_not flash.empty?
            assert_template 'password_resets/new'
            # Valid email
            post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: @user.email }
            assert_not_equal @user.reset_digest, @user.reload.reset_digest
            assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
            assert_not flash.empty?
            assert_redirected_to root_url
            # Password reset form
            user = assigns(:user)
            # Valid password & confirmation
            patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
            email: user.email,
            user: {
                password: "foobaz",
                password_confirmation: "foobaz"
            }
        end
    end

    def create_reset_digest
        self.reset_token = User.new_token
        #creating reset_digest
    end    

    def create
        @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
        if @user
            @user.create_reset_digest

        # ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked a source - author of the book, Michael Hartl :)

His answer: "It's been a while since I looked at that code, but I think what's going on is that `@user` has a `reset_digest` but not a `reset_token`. The `post` to the password resets path changes the `@user` variable in the `create` method, but that's not the same variable as the one in the test. That's why the call to `assigns` is necessary: the `@user` in the test doesn't have the virtual `reset_token` attribute, but the one in the controller does."

To be honest, I still don't get it - why reset_digest of test variable "@user" changes, if it's not the variable which is influenced by create action?